# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined in renderHook import

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I am trying to use renderHook from the testing-library.
When I run my test I get this error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.10.1",
    "@testing-library/preact": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.5",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-minify-constant-folding": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "dot-prop": "^5.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.142.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "kind-of": "^6.0.3",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.2",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "prettier-stylelint": "0.4.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "stylelint": "12.0.0",
    "wait-for-expect": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

my unit test file is

```
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick } from '../usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick';

describe('usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick', () => {
  it('should call the callback onBackButtonClick', () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn();
    const { result } = renderHook(() =>
      usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick(mockCallback)
    );
    act(() => result.current());
    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The error message when I run the unit test is
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

````
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

    > 19 | import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
         | ^

      22 | import { usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick } from '../usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick';

      at node_modules/.pnpm/react-test-renderer@16.9.0_react@16.13.1/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:153:27
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/.pnpm/react-test-renderer@16.9.0_react@16.13.1/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15959:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/.pnpm/react-test-renderer@16.9.0_react@16.13.1/node_modules/react-test-renderer/index.js:6:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library/react-hooks@3.4.1_0d7f26cd33b086e6db0ec263aae150bb/node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks/lib/pure.js:28:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library/react-hooks@3.4.1_0d7f26cd33b086e6db0ec263aae150bb/node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks/lib/index.js:13:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/common/hooks/tests/usePlayBeepingSoundAndBackButtonClick.test.js:19:1)
    ```
````